# Подскажите можно ли все кешь который лежит в папке var/cache фреймворка Symfony запихнуть в Redis?

Tags: symfony, кэширование, redis

Всем привет!
Подскажите можно ли все кешь который лежит в папке var/cache фреймворка Symfony запихнуть в Redis?

Comment: Но зачем ?  Вы считаете что так будет быстрее ? Не будет. Используйте Opcache и не придумывайте велосипеды.

Comment: Но если это исключительно академический интерес, то попросту подмонтируйте нужную вам папку в память.  https://www.mvps.net/docs/how-to-mount-the-physical-memory-from-a-linux-system-as-a-partition/